# Symfony 2.3.6 generate CRUD panel from FOSuserbundle

Tags: symfony, crud, fosuserbundle

I trying to create CRUD panel from FOSUserBundle but i have some troubles. I mean that i created User entity for FOS and made crud panel for this entity. Now when i trying to add new user i have error like below

> Neither the property "expiresAt" nor one of the methods "getExpiresAt()", "isExpiresAt()", "hasExpiresAt()", "_*get()" or "*_call()" exist and have public access in class "Bn\UserBundle\Entity\User".

It's my first project so please understand when i will ask for simple function, some suggestion ? What is wrong ?

Comment: I am just looking at this again... I assume your entity `Bn\UserBundle\Entity\User` inherits from `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`. The parent class should have setters/getters for `expiresAt`. So it seems a little strange. Can you post your `User` entity's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace Bn\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get expiresAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getExpiresAt()
    {
        return $this->expiresAt;
    }

    /**
     * Get credentials_expire_at
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCredentialsExpireAt()
    {
        return $this->credentialsExpireAt;
    }


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Now is working but i don't know why i must declare again function for getter.

Comment: I have tried the above code but still that's not working, is that something you missed to specify?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this means you need to add public accessors `setExpiresAt()` and `getExpiresAt()` to your `User` entity.

Answer (score 0):

You need only add getExpiresAt to your User.php class. FOSUserBundle\User doesn't have getter for this field, but Sensio generator creates views for all fields.

```
public function getExpiresAt()
{
    return $this->expiresAt;
}
```